# how to iterate over an cursor

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have an select statement that  returns  a   single  row.
After that  I  have  written a  cursor as for  me @@fetch_status is -1 it  does not  go inside the cursor only now

```
open cur_mkt    
print @init 
While (@init = 0)      
Begin      
fetch next from cur_mkt into       
@Desc,      
@Divisions      
print @@fetch_status
if (@@fetch_status =-1)      
BREAK
```

Is there  any way I  can go inside the  cursor,
please help me out.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It doesn't sound like you need a cursor (which you should try to avoid anyway). If you're determining the presence of a result you could do:

```
SELECT @Desc = Desc, @Divisions = Divisions
FROM YourTable
WHERE ID = 1

IF ( @@ROWCOUNT > 0 )
    BEGIN
        -- Row was found
    END
```

So I would recommend not using cursors.

To directly answer the question, the way you use cursors/iterate round the results is as follows:

```
DECLARE @A INTEGER

DECLARE cur_mkt CURSOR FOR
SELECT 1 AS A 
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS A

OPEN cur_mkt
FETCH NEXT FROM cur_mkt INTO @A

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
    BEGIN
        PRINT @A    
        FETCH NEXT FROM cur_mkt INTO @A
    END

CLOSE cur_mkt
DEALLOCATE cur_mkt
```